# can native only code run on android as standalone application

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-ndk

We want to migrate a huge complex native program to Android system ,running it as a background service accepting command sent from Java Program using JNI along with IPC. However, the Android NDK state following words:

> Please note that the NDK does not enable you to develop native-only applications. Android's primary runtime remains the Dalvik virtual machine.

Does that mean we have no way to run an standalone native-only application on Android as a background service? The native code can only exist in the form of library that will be loaded to the  virtual machine through JNI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The NDK itself is only for creating libraries, though if you do some web searching you will find that there are at least two sets of wrapper scripts or instructions for (ab)using its toolchain to make standalone executables linked against android's bionic libc (something you would not get from a non-android arm toolchain).

The google folks do not encourage people to do this.  Unfortunately, their vision of android only includes java applications, with optional native libraries in support - it does not include any "stable" means of installing or launching a native executable, in the sense that they warn the methods you might be able to use today may not continue to work in new versions.  This is really too bad, as it means giving up a lot of the general-purpose-computer potential of the device.

Comment: Well, with current NDK it is also possible to build "native-only" applications, although that just means that *your* code is only native (no Java wrapper required), the system will provide the Java wrapper (NativeActivity). You still will be running within a VM.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it can be done. But to be honest i've never tried it using the NDK, but i've managed to create native applications using the toolchains provided with the android source code.

Your phone (incase your talking about phones) should be rooted.

Comment: Rooting the phone is not necessary for stand alone native applications to work, however it does open up the possibilities for where on the device you can store an executable file (many of the obvious choices being mounted noexec).